# Strtol second argument

Tags: c++, string, parsing, strtol

How does the second argument of `strtol` work?

Here is what I tried:

```
strtol(str, &ptr, 10)
```

where `ptr` is a `char *` and `str` is a string. Now, If I pass in `str` as `'34EF'`, and print `*ptr`, it correctly gives me `E`, and `*(ptr+1)` gives me `F`, however if I print `ptr`, it gives me `EF!` Shouldn't printing `ptr` just result in a  rubbish value like a hex address or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ptr` is a pointer to the interior of a null terminated string. So given `"34EF"` it ends up pointing to the character `'E'` and the string starting at that address is `"EF"`.

A four-character C string like `p = "34EF"` actually contains five strings in one. The string `p` is `"34EF"`. The string `p+1` is `"4EF"`; the string `p+2` is `"EF"`; `p+3` is `"F"` and `p+4` is the empty string `""`. In this case `p+4` points to the null terminator byte after the `F`.

Speaking of the empty string, if the input to `strtol` consists only of valid characters making up the numeric token, then `ptr` should point to an empty string.

If you want to disallow trailing junk, you can test for this. That is, even if a valid number parses out, if `*ptr` is not 0, then the input has trailing junk. In some cases, it is good to reject that: "Dear user, 10Zdf is not a number; please enter a number!"

Comment: No, it isn't an analogy. There are actually, physically five strings there, condensed into a small storage space due to sharing a common suffix. If it were an analogy, I would have included wording that it's an analogy.